# Assistance with Index in Java - programming 1

Tags: java, if-statement

could someone please help me with this?

Write a single `if...else statement` that outputs whether or not
 the line of text contains any of these lower-case words: 
 `"the"`, `"and"`, `"hello"`

i tried this but don't think its correct so far:

```
if(line.indexOf("the") >= 0 || line.indexOf("and") >= 0)
    System.out.print( "Contains one of the words");
        else (
```

Comment: Very hard to say if it is correct as you stopped mid statement...

Comment: wasn't sure where to go from there..am i on the right path though?

Comment: Is it ok for `and` to find word `band`? If yes, then you're on the right path. If no, then you need to use `split()` or a regular expression.

Comment: im new to CS i havent learnt "split" yet

Answer (score 2):

To determine if a `String` contains *any* of three words, I would use [`String.contains(CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) and something like

```
 if (line.contains("the") || line.contains("and") || line.contains("hello")) {
     System.out.println(line + " contains the, and or hello");
 } else {
     System.out.println(line + " does not contain the, and or hello");           
 }
```

But your current approach should work if you add "hello" like (and it's a `{` after else, not `(`).

```
if (line.indexOf("the") >= 0 || line.indexOf("and") >= 0 
        || line.indexOf("hello") >= 0) {
     System.out.println(line + " contains the, and or hello");
} else {
     System.out.println(line + " does not contain the, and or hello");           
}
```

However, I note that you omitted the braces in your example. You can do that, but then your statements only apply to the next line.

```
if (line.indexOf("the") >= 0 || line.indexOf("and") >= 0 
        || line.indexOf("hello") >= 0)
     System.out.println(line + " contains the, and or hello");
else
     System.out.println(line + " does not contain the, and or hello");
```

And you can mix braces like

```
if (line.indexOf("the") >= 0 || line.indexOf("and") >= 0 
        || line.indexOf("hello") >= 0) {
     System.out.println(line + " contains the, and or hello");
} else
     System.out.println(line + " does not contain the, and or hello");
```

Or

```
if (line.indexOf("the") >= 0 || line.indexOf("and") >= 0 
        || line.indexOf("hello") >= 0)
     System.out.println(line + " contains the, and or hello");
else {
     System.out.println(line + " does not contain the, and or hello");           
}
```

But I **prefer** to *always* use braces.

Comment: Thank you really appreciate it !